# Wpf MVVM binding List<List<string>> to datagrid

Tags: wpf, binding

I want bind property of model to datagrid, i can't do it
I have property in model
model contains list with list of strings
rows count is constant  in list

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public TestViewModel()
            : this(new FileService())
        {
        }

        public TestViewModel(IFileService fileService)
        {

            var list = new List<List<string>>();
            list.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
            list.Add(new List<string>() { "3", "4", "5" });
            RecodListFromCsv = list;
        }

        private List<List<string>> _RecodListFromCsv;

        public List<List<string>> RecodListFromCsv
        {
            get { return _RecodListFromCsv; }
            set
            {
                if (_RecodListFromCsv != value)
                {
                    _RecodListFromCsv = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("RecodListFromCsv");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Views.TestView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewsModel"
        Title="PriceList" Height="427" Width="746">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:TestViewModelx:Key="TM" />
    </Window.Resources>    
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TM}}">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding RecodListFromCsv}">
            </DataGrid>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and UI show 
[image]

What I'm doing wrong. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Each row item of datagrid is type of `List<string>` so auto generating column of datagrid generate public property of `List<string>` object(Capacity,Count)!. So to resolve this quickly instead of `List<List<string>>` using `List<Tuple<string,string,string>>` if your items number is 3.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string,string,string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string,string,string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
list.Add(new Tuple<string,string,string>() { "3", "4", "5" });
RecodListFromCsv = list;
```

The stable solution is create a persistent class and create list of that object class properly.